# How can I import video files with NSOpenPanel?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsopenpanel

I want to import video files with NSOpenPanel. How can I do it?

I want play this video on a avkit player. Maybe you could help with playing the video file as well?

**This is the code I wrote**

```
        let filePicker: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()

    filePicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    filePicker.canChooseFiles = true
    filePicker.canChooseDirectories = false
    filePicker.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
    filePicker.styleMask.insert(.unifiedTitleAndToolbar)
    filePicker.styleMask.insert(.titled)
    filePicker.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    filePicker.runModal()

    let chosenFile = filePicker.url

    if chosenFile != nil
    {
        let imageImport = NSImage(contentsOf: chosenFile!)
    }
```

I tried to find tutorials about it, but it seems like this isn't a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `allowedFileTypes` property, along with the [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) system.

If you want to filter for any files that Mac OS X consider a movie file, regardless of extension, pass in `public.movie`:

```
filePicker.allowedFileTypes = ["public.movie"]
```

If you want to filter for only MPEG-4 files, a specific movie format, pass in a different UTI:

```
filePicker.allowedFileTypes = [kUTTypeMPEG4 as String] // kUTTypeMPEG4 == "public.mpeg-4"
```

If you want to only allow files with extension of `.mp4` (one of several extensions allowed for MPEG-4 encoding), pass the extension in:

```
filePicker.allowedFileTypes = ["mp4"]
```

The examples goes from most generic (all types of movie files), to more specific (only MPEG-4 encoded files) to most restricted (only `.mp4` files). Choose one that suits your needs.